# Obfuscate my source code in android

Tags: android

I tried something like this in `project.properties`:

`proguard.config=proguard.cfg`

Debugging worked but when trying to export it as Signed, it tells me that it can't find `proguard.cfg`

I tried putting instead 
`proguard.config=proguard-project.txt`
but it changed something with my program and it seems not working as i want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

Answer (score 1):

your code is only obfuscated by proguard if you run `ant` in release mode
through commandline `ant release` or through release build in eclipse (does the same),
both result in a signed app.
and only if you do this, proguard is enabled.

so, the error says, there is no proguard.cfg in your app's directory,
try this preconfigured proguard file instead:

in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

or if you want a optimized build:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

if you don't have a `proguard-project.txt` in your app's directory,
just drop the `:proguard-project.txt` at the line ending.

should work ;)